# Distribution Convergence of an Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

I need to show that 
$$\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\theta +1}\left(\frac{1}{\bar{X}_n}-1-\theta \right) \to^{d} N(0,1)$$
where $\bar{X}_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ and iid random variables $X_i$, $X_1 \tilde{\;}\exp(\theta+1) $. However i onyl succeed at proving this without the $\sqrt{2}$. ($\to^{d}$ stands for convergence in distribution).
$$\frac{\sqrt{2n}}{\theta +1}\left(\frac{1}{\bar{X}_n}-1-\theta \right) = - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{(\theta+1)\bar{X}_n} \cdot \sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n*(\theta+1)-1) \quad \star$$
where $$\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n*(\theta+1)-1)  \to^{d} N(0,1)$$ by the central limit theorem. 
$$\bar{X}_n \to \frac{1}{\theta+1}$$ by some strong limit theorem and so 
$$- \frac{\sqrt{2}}{(\theta+1)\bar{X}_n} \to^d -\sqrt{2} $$ by the theorem of slutsky for multiplication.
The $''-''$ doesnt really matter, because if $Z \tilde{} N(0,1)$ then it is $-Z \tilde{} N(0,1)$ as well. 
I cannot find my mistake. Looking forward to any help. If you thik my mistake lies in the Line marked by the $\star$ i might write my steps as well.

Thanks.

Comment: Your equation $\star$ is not correct. The right-hand side should say
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{(\theta+1)\bar{X_n}}\cdot \sqrt{n}(1-\bar{X_n}(\theta+1)).$$
But I'm not sure if that expression will be helpful or not.

Comment: Yeah, i made this mistake whil typing my notes in to latex, the Central limit theorem was only copy paste of the $\star$ term. So now it should be correct.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me either where the $\sqrt{2}$ comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\sqrt 2$ was a mistake in the exercise.